# Error in ITSA modelling in R using ITS.analysis

Tags: r

I'm using the its.analysis package in R to analyse my data, a sample of which looks like this:

```
interrupt   estimate date      
      <dbl>    <dbl> <date>    
      0    1.03  2018-01-01
      0    1.10  2018-02-01
      0    1.08  2018-03-01
      0    1.05  2018-04-01
      1    1.01  2018-05-01
      1    1.16  2018-06-01
      1    1.13  2018-07-01
      1    1.12  2018-08-01
      1    0.964 2018-09-01
      1    1.01  2018-10-01
```

I've tried to run this:

```
itsa.model(data=itsa, time="date", depv="estimate", interrupt_var = "interrupt", alpha=0.05, bootstrap=TRUE, Reps = 250)
```

but get this error:

```
Error in eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'depvar' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
2: In data.frame(depvar = data[, depvar], interrupt_var = as.factor(data[,  :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this and wonder if someone could assist...thanks!

Comment: With the posted data I'm getting a different error: ```Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels```.

Answer (score 0):

I realised it needed to be passed into a dataframe. I wrapped the data with as.data.frame() and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).